# How to shorten this OCaml code?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am just wondering how to shorten these code as I suspect it is too redundant

```
let get ename doc = 
  try Some (StringMap.find ename doc) with Not_found -> None;;

let get_double ename doc = 
  let element = get ename doc in
  match element with
    | None -> None
    | Some (Double v) -> Some v
    | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type;;

let get_string ename doc = 
  let element = get ename doc in
  match element with
    | None -> None
    | Some (String v) -> Some v
    | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type;;

let get_doc ename doc = 
  let element = get ename doc in
  match element with
    | None -> None
    | Some (Document v) -> Some v
    | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type;;
```

So, basically, I have different types of values, and I put all those kinds of values into a map.

The code above is for getting according type of values out of the map. What I do is that for each type, I have a get. To get one type of value, I have to see a). whether it is there or not; b). whether it is that type indeed, if not, raise an exception.

But the code above seems to redundant as you can see. The only diff between each type's get is just the type itself.

How can I shorten this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let get_generic extract ename doc =
  let element = get ename doc in
  match element with
    | None -> None
    | Some v -> Some (extract v)

let get_double = get_generic (function Double v -> v | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type)
let get_string = get_generic (function String v -> v | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type)
let get_doc = get_generic (function Document v -> v | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type)
```

EDIT:
To remove the redundant `raise Wrong_bson_type` (But it is ugly):

```
let get_generic extract ename doc = try
  let element = get ename doc in
  match element with
    | None -> None
    | Some v -> Some (extract v)
with Match_failure _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type

let get_double = get_generic (fun (Double v) -> v)
let get_string = get_generic (fun (String v) -> v)
let get_doc = get_generic (fun (Document v)-> v)
```

Comment: can we even remove the redundant `raise Wrong_bson_type`

Comment: also do we need () for Double v? like fun (Double v) -> ...`

Comment: Yes you need parentheses. It is ugly because the pattern matching is not exhaustive.

Comment: do you think this function definition is correct `fun (Document v) -> v | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type`? for example, i can't do `exception Wrong_bson_type;; let f = fun x -> 1 | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type;;`the syntax of the match is wrong

Comment: Sorry, you have to use `function` instead of `fun`.

Comment: yeah fun is more like a SML style?

Comment: Yes, `function ...` is equivalent to `fun e -> match e with ...` (or looking at it the other way, `match e with ...` is equivalent to `(function ...) e`), while `fun a b c -> ...` is equivalent to `fun a -> fun b -> fun c -> ...` (not possible with `function`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use GADT to do that:

If you define a type `expr` like this:

```
type _ expr =
  | Document: document -> document expr
  | String: string -> string expr
  | Double: float -> float expr
```

You can write a function `get` like this:

```
let get : type v. v expr -> v = function
   Document doc -> doc
 | String s -> s
 | Double d -> d
```

Comment: sorry, I did mean to use get_type style as I want the user to make sure explicitly exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

With GADTs:

```
type _ asked = 
 | TDouble : float asked
 | TString : string asked
 | TDocument : document asked

let get : type v. v asked -> string -> doc StringMap.t -> v option = 
  fun asked ename doc ->
  try
    Some (match asked, StringMap.find ename doc with
         | TDouble, Double f -> f
         | TString, String s -> s
         | TDocument, Document d -> d)
  with Not_found -> None

let get_double = get TDouble
let get_string = get TString
let get_document = get TDocument
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with these extractor functions:

```ml
let extract_double = function
  | Double v -> v
  | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type

let extract_string = function
  | String v -> v
  | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type

let extract_doc = function
  | Document v -> v
  | _ -> raise Wrong_bson_type
```

Then you can use monadic style for the higher-order function, which allows you to keep your original definition of `get`:

```
let return x = Some x

let (>>=) mx f = 
  match mx with
    | Some x -> f x
    | None -> None

let get_with exf ename doc =
  (get ename doc) >>= fun v -> 
  return (exf v)

let get_double = get_with extract_double
let get_string = get_with extract_string
let get_doc = get_with extract_doc
```

Less redundant and abstracts the side effect to generic bind and return operations.